# Java LinkedList fast writes (moving, removing or adding),but accessing objects is slow.That is Why?

Tags: java, linked-list

Many people said Java LinkedList adding objects is faster than accessing objects.I've checked Java LinkedList source code and i found not like this.Code as follows:

```
public void add(int index, E element) {
    checkPositionIndex(index);

    if (index == size)
        linkLast(element);
    else
        linkBefore(element, node(index));
}

public E get(int index) {
    checkElementIndex(index);
    return node(index).item;
}

Node<E> node(int index) {
    // assert isElementIndex(index);

    if (index < (size >> 1)) {
        Node<E> x = first;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            x = x.next;
        return x;
    } else {
        Node<E> x = last;
        for (int i = size - 1; i > index; i--)
            x = x.prev;
        return x;
    }
}
```

In add method,if index!=size so node method will be called.The same is true for get.

For node method,it will traverse to the node before.So i think add method and get method is the same for performance.i am very confused.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Adding to the *end* of a linked list avoids the `node()` call and is `O(1)`. However, adding to the middle of a linked list is `O(n/2)` ~ `O(n)`. (Adding close to either end is also 'fast' but the add-to-end optimization only occurs when .. adding to end.) Likewise, *iterating* the linked list (or accessing the head/tail elements, or elements close to either end) is 'fast', but random access of a linked is is `O(n)`.

Comment: I think you should paste specific quote(s) from the many people. I think you may be misinterpreting it, or they were more specific about the case. Because you are correct, they are the same when an `index` is involved, the code needs to find that item in the same manor. They may have been comparing to another datatype, like an array or `ArrayList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `LinkedList` is actually a List of Objects called Nodes. Each Node has an object that it contains and a reference to the next Node. When you add an object to the list you are actually making a new Node that has the object in it and the old last Node now has a reference to the new last Node.

So let's say you have a `LinkedList` of Strings with 2 Strings in it. The first object in the list is a Node with the first String and a reference to the next Node and the second String is in the Node (which the first one has a reference to). Now if you want to add a String a new Node is created and the String is placed in the Node. The Node with the second String is now given a reference to the Node with the 3rd String.

The way a `get` in `LinkedList` works is that it starts at the first Node and keeps looking at the reference to the next Node until it's at the index you placed in the `get` parameter, at which point it returns the Object in that Node. That's why it takes so long. It needs to iterate from the beginning to the index every time the `get` method is called.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct. *That* `add()` method is *O(N).* It is the no-arguments `add()` method which is *O(1)*, or this one if adding at the end.